# Self-refercing condition in aggregate function

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

I have a real usecase from a fish farm where the growth of a farm from being fed depends on the average size of the fish in the farm when the fish are fed. I have reduced this problem to what I believe to be the core of what I am unable to express in PostgreSQL: an aggregate function with a condition in it that depends on the value of the previous calculation of that aggregate.

The data operated on is a series of transactions.

```sql
create table transactions (
    id           bigserial primary key,
    feed_g       bigint  
);

insert into transactions
    (feed_g)
values
    (50),
    (50),
    (50),
    (50);
```

Calculating a sum over these rows is simple.

```sql
select
    id,
    feed_g,
    sum(feed_g) over (order by id) as simple_sum
from transactions;

--  id | feed_g | simple_sum 
-- ----+--------+------------
--   1 |     50 |         50
--   2 |     50 |        100
--   3 |     50 |        150
--   4 |     50 |        200
```

Calculating a sum with a conditional that depends on the value of the input row is also simple. In the below query the second case will always be used.

```sql
select
    id,
    feed_g,
    sum(
        case when feed_g > 75 then feed_g
             else                  feed_g * 0.5
        end
    ) over (order by id) as row_weighted_sum
from transactions;

--  id | feed_g | row_weighted_sum 
-- ----+--------+------------------
--   1 |     50 |             25.0
--   2 |     50 |             50.0
--   3 |     50 |             75.0
--   4 |     50 |            100.0
```

What I cannot figure out how to do is to write a query where the conditional in the aggregate function depends on the output calculated by the same aggregate function for the previous row.

Below is some non-working pseudo-SQL for that.

```sql
select
    id,
    feed_g,
    sum(
        case when lag(recursive_sum) + feed_g  > 75 then feed_g
             else                                        feed_g * 0.5
        end
    ) over (order by id) as recursive_sum
from transactions;

-- The imagined output would be the following:
--  id | feed_g | row_weighted_sum 
-- ----+--------+------------------
--   1 |     50 |             25.0
--   2 |     50 |             50.0
--   3 |     50 |            100.0
--   4 |     50 |            150.0
```

Using the `simple_sum` as the input to the `recursive_sum` does not seem like a viable solution as they will drift apart over time. In the given small example dataset this drift has affect on row two where the `simple_sum` crosses the threshold on row 2 when it should not occur until row 3.

```sql
with estimate as (
    select
        id,
        feed_g,
        sum(feed_g) over (order by id) as simple_sum
    from transactions
)
select
    id,
    feed_g,
    simple_sum,
    sum(
        case when simple_sum > 75 then feed_g
             else                      feed_g * 0.5
        end
    ) over (order by id) as simple_sum_weighted_sum
from estimate;

--  id | feed_g | simple_sum | simple_sum_weighted_sum 
-- ----+--------+------------+-------------------------
--   1 |     50 |         50 |                    25.0
--   2 |     50 |        100 |                    75.0
--   3 |     50 |        150 |                   125.0
--   4 |     50 |        200 |                   175.0
```

A third step that uses the `simple_sum_weighted_sum` as input in a call to `lag` does not work out either as it "forgets" the weighting of everything but the last row.

```sql
with estimate as (
    select
        id,
        feed_g,
        sum(feed_g) over (order by id) as simple_sum
    from transactions
),
est2 as (
select
    id,
    feed_g,
    simple_sum,
    sum(
        case when simple_sum > 75 then feed_g
             else                      feed_g * 0.5
        end
    ) over (order by id) as simple_sum_weighted_sum
from estimate)
select
    id,
    feed_g,
    simple_sum,
    simple_sum_weighted_sum,
    coalesce(lag(simple_sum_weighted_sum) over (order by id), 0)
        + case when simple_sum_weighted_sum > 75 then feed_g
               else                                   feed_g * 0.5
          end as row_weighted_sum
from est2;

--  id | feed_g | simple_sum | simple_sum_weighted_sum | row_weighted_sum 
-- ----+--------+------------+-------------------------+------------------
--   1 |     50 |         50 |                    25.0 |             25.0
--   2 |     50 |        100 |                    75.0 |             50.0
--   3 |     50 |        150 |                   125.0 |            125.0
--   4 |     50 |        200 |                   175.0 |            175.0
```

I wrote two working implementations of the algorithm in Python for reference. This first one in imperative style.

```python
data = (50, 50, 50, 50)
sum = 0
for value in data:
  if sum + value > 75:
    sum = sum + value
  else:
    sum = sum + value * 0.5
  print(value, sum)

# 50 25.0
# 50 50.0
# 50 100.0
# 50 150.0
```

This second one in a somewhat stunted functional style.

```python
data = (50, 50, 50, 50)

def data_dependant_recursive_sum(iterator, last_sum):
  try:
    value = next(iterator)
  except StopIteration:
    return
  recursively_weighted_value = value if last_sum + value > 75 else value * 0.5
  recursive_sum = recursively_weighted_value + last_sum
  print(value, recursive_sum)
  data_dependant_recursive_sum(iterator, recursive_sum)
  
data_dependant_recursive_sum(iter(data), 0)

# 50 25.0
# 50 50.0
# 50 100.0
# 50 150.0
```

If this exercise feels contrived and nonsensical, a much more complicated but complete version of this question can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70158295

I am currently using Postgres 12 but an upgrade to 14 would be easy if that is required.

Comment: Just like the comments of your StackOverflow question, I was going to suggest doing your query in two steps, since you cannot use a window function inside of a window function. But as long as your logic is correct, you should be able to calculate the `SUM()` window function first, then calculate your *adjusted* `recursive_sum` with the `LAG()` window function second.

Comment: I edited the question and added two examples where I try to do a split like that. Are those splits like what you imagined or am I missing some detail in your text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires a recursive CTE. Here is an example in TSQL (postgres should be similar):

```
declare @transactions as table (
    id integer primary key identity(1,1),
    feed_g integer
);

insert into @transactions 
values (50), (50), (50), (50);

with indexed_transactions as (
    select *, row_number() over (order by id) as rn
    from @transactions
),
cte as (
    select cast(0 as bigint) as rn, 0 as id, 0 as feed_g, cast(0.0 as float) as row_weighted_sum

    union all
    select
        a.rn,
        a.id,
        a.feed_g,
        case when cte.row_weighted_sum + a.feed_g > 75 then cte.row_weighted_sum + a.feed_g
        else cte.row_weighted_sum + a.feed_g * 0.5 end as row_weighted_sum
    from indexed_transactions a
    join cte on cte.rn = a.rn - 1
)
select * from cte where id > 0
```

Results:

```
rn  id  feed_g  row_weighted_sum
1   1   50      25
2   2   50      50
3   3   50      100
4   4   50      150
```

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, here is Isak's answer translated to PostgreSQL.

```sql
with recursive indexed_transactions as (
    select *, row_number() over (order by id)
    from transactions
),
cte as (
    select 0::bigint as row_number, 0::bigint as id, 0::bigint as feed_g, 0::float as row_weighted_sum
    union all
    select
        a.row_number,
        a.id,
        a.feed_g,
        case when cte.row_weighted_sum + a.feed_g > 75
            then cte.row_weighted_sum + a.feed_g
            else cte.row_weighted_sum + a.feed_g * 0.5
        end as row_weighted_sum
    from indexed_transactions a
    join cte on cte.row_number = a.row_number - 1
)
select * from cte where id > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a working implementation in Python, you could simply convert it into a PL/Python function in PostgreSQL. While it should be possible to come up with a pure SQL solution, the task is effectively a procedural one, so a procedural solution might be the best fit.